# Input a dynamic array in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, java.util.scanner

I am trying to input a dynamic array, the size is unknown at any point with input like this(Example)

1 5 1 4 3 2

but cannot figure out how. I have a code that works partially but still need a perfect solution.

My Code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int T;
T = sc.nextInt();
for(int i=0; i<T;i++){
List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();;
int n=0;
String temp;
do{
     temp = sc.next();
     a.add(Integer.parseInt(temp));
     n++;
}while(sc.hasNextInt());
myfxn(a);
}
```

this code waits until a non-numeric value is entered then it proceeds, I thought it would take Enter as that but it didn't. So I need to execute my code in a way that they take the whole array until an Enter is fired or line ends.

Comment: Well, this is what `hasNextInt` does, so if you want to insert values one by one with `Enter` only the user can decide when to stop input. For example you could check for a specific value that the user needs to know in order to stop the input.

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara no actually, I want to enter them with spaces but end the input with an Enter or new Line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer with some help, here is the code

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T;
    T = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    for(int i=0; i<T;i++){
        List<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();;
        int n=0;
        String data = sc.nextLine();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(data);
        while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
            a.add(scanner.nextInt());
            n++;
        }
        myfxn(a);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want your user to enter the values separated by space and end with new line.... try this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
     int i = 0;
   List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
    while(i<args.length){
         try{
              int temp = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
           values.add(temp);
          }catch(){}

         i++;

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get input along with a space as a string.

```
String input= scanner.nextLine();
```

now split that string with space.

```
String [] array= input.split(" ");
```

Now the entered value will be available as an array, parse it if you need an integer.